# R: how can I split one row of a time period into multiple rows based on day and time

Tags: r, date, datetime

I am trying to split rows in an excel file based on day and time. The data is from a study which participants will need to wear a tracking watch. Each row of the data set is started with participants put on the watch (Variable: 'Wear Time Start ') and ended with them taking off the device (Variable: 'Wear Time End').

I need to calculate how many hours of each participant wearing the device on each day (NOT each time period in one row).

Data set before split:

```
   ID          WearStart                WearEnd
1  01           2018-05-14 09:00:00      2018-05-14 20:00:00
2  01           2018-05-14 21:30:00      2018-05-15 02:00:00
3  01           2018-05-15 07:00:00      2018-05-16 22:30:00
4  01           2018-05-16 23:00:00      2018-05-16 23:40:00
5  01           2018-05-17 01:00:00      2018-05-19 15:00:00
6  02           ...
```

Some explanation about the data set before split:  the data type of 'WearStart' and 'WearEnd' are POSIXlt.

Desired output after split:

```
  ID         WearStart                WearEnd                Interval
1 01         2018-05-14 09:00:00      2018-05-14 20:00:00    11
2 01         2018-05-14 21:30:00      2018-05-15 00:00:00    2.5
3 01         2018-05-15 00:00:00      2018-05-15 02:00:00    2                
4 01         2018-05-15 07:00:00      2018-05-16 00:00:00    17
5 01         2018-05-16 00:00:00      2018-05-16 22:30:00    22.5
4 01         2018-05-16 23:00:00      2018-05-16 23:40:00    0.4
5 01         2018-05-17 01:00:00      2018-05-18 00:00:00    23
6 01         2018-05-18 00:00:00      2018-05-19 00:00:00    24
7 01         2018-05-19 00:00:00      2018-05-19 15:00:00    15
```

Then I need to accumulate hours based on day:

```
  ID         Wear_Day        Total_Hours
1 01         2018-05-14      13.5
2 01         2018-05-15      19
3 01         2018-05-16      22.9                
4 01         2018-05-17      23
5 01         2018-05-18      24
4 01         2018-05-19      15
```

Comment: Are you splitting by day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I reworked the entire answer. Please, review the code. I am pretty sure this is what you want.

**Short summary**

The problem is that you need to split rows which start and end on different dates. And you need to do this recursively. So, I split the dataframe into a list of 1-row dataframes. For each I check whether start and end is on the same day. If not, I make it a 2-row dataframe with the adjusted start and end times. This is then split up again into a list of 1-row dataframes and so on so forth.
In the end there is a nested list of 1-row dataframes where start and end is on the same day. And this list is then recursively bound together again.

```
# Load Packages ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- tribble(
    ~ID,         ~WearStart,              ~WearEnd    
    , 01, "2018-05-14 09:00:00", "2018-05-14 20:00:00"
    , 01, "2018-05-14 21:30:00", "2018-05-15 02:00:00"
    , 01, "2018-05-15 07:00:00", "2018-05-16 22:30:00"
    , 01, "2018-05-16 23:00:00", "2018-05-16 23:40:00"
    , 01, "2018-05-17 01:00:00", "2018-05-19 15:00:00"
)
df <- df %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Wear")), ymd_hms)


# Helper Functions ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

endsOnOtherDay <- function(df){
    as_date(df$WearStart) != as_date(df$WearEnd)
}

split1rowInto2Days <- function(df){
    df1 <- df
    df2 <- df
    df1$WearEnd <- as_date(df1$WearStart) + days(1) - milliseconds(1)
    df2$WearStart <- as_date(df2$WearStart) + days(1)
    rbind(df1, df2)
}


splitDates <- function(df){
    if (nrow(df) > 1){
        return(df %>%
                   split(f = 1:nrow(df)) %>%
                   lapply(splitDates) %>%
                   reduce(rbind))
    }

    if (df %>% endsOnOtherDay()){
        return(df %>%
                   split1rowInto2Days() %>%
                   splitDates())
    }

    df
}

# The actual Calculation ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

df %>% 
    splitDates() %>%
    mutate(wearDuration = difftime(WearEnd, WearStart, units = "hours")
           , wearDay = as_date(WearStart)) %>%
    group_by(ID, wearDay) %>%
    summarise(wearDuration_perDay = sum(wearDuration))

     ID wearDay    wearDuration_perDay
  <dbl> <date>     <drtn>             
1     1 2018-05-14 13.50000 hours     
2     1 2018-05-15 19.00000 hours     
3     1 2018-05-16 23.16667 hours     
4     1 2018-05-17 23.00000 hours     
5     1 2018-05-18 24.00000 hours     
6     1 2018-05-19 15.00000 hours
```

Comment: @huluwa Can you please check this?

Comment: Hi @Georgery,  sorry that I did not check the website during the holidays. Thank you so much for your work!! You saved me days of work to spit the days. I tried your code on a small part of my data and it ran perfectly. However I encountered an error that caused R to close. I am trying to figure out why and I will update here.

Comment: I fixed the problem! Although still not sure what exactly happened, I did some modification in the data type and your code fit all my data well. Great thanks again!

Comment: Regarding errors: if your dataset is **really** big (millions of rows) and the wear durations very often are multiple days, you might run into memory issues. The point is that this is a recursive function, i.e. it calls itself again and again which can lead to a deeply nested structure of function calls and therefore memory usage. This version here is very elegant, but for very big datasets a function with a `for`loop might be better.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I learned a lot from your code.  Sure! but New to the functions on Stackoverflow. How to mark an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to your question with just using basic functions in R:

```
#step 1: read data from file
d <- read.csv("dt.csv", header = TRUE)
d
   ID           WearStart             WearEnd
1  1 2018-05-14 09:00:00 2018-05-14 20:00:00
2  1 2018-05-14 21:30:00 2018-05-15 02:00:00
3  1 2018-05-15 07:00:00 2018-05-16 22:30:00
4  1 2018-05-16 23:00:00 2018-05-16 23:40:00
5  1 2018-05-17 01:00:00 2018-05-19 15:00:00
6  2 2018-05-16 11:30:00 2018-05-16 11:40:00
7  2 2018-05-16 22:05:00 2018-05-22 22:42:00

#step 2: change class of WearStart and WearEnd to POSIlct
d$WearStart <- as.POSIXlt(d$WearStart, tryFormats = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
d$WearEnd   <- as.POSIXlt(d$WearEnd, tryFormats = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

#step 3: calculate time interval (days and hours) for each record
timeInt <- function(d) {
        WearStartDay  <- as.Date(d$WearStart, "%Y/%m/%d")
        Interval_days <- as.numeric(difftime(d$WearEnd,d$WearStart, units = "days"))
        Days <- WearStartDay + seq(0, Interval_days,1)
        N_FullBTWDays <- length(Days) - 2 

        if (N_FullBTWDays >= 0) {
           sd   <- d$WearStart
           sd_h <- 24 - sd$hour -1
           sd_m <- (60 - sd$min)/60
           sd_total <- sd_h + sd_m
           hours <- sd_total
           hours <- c(hours, rep(24,N_FullBTWDays))
           ed   <- d$WearEnd
           ed_h <- ed$hour
           ed_m <- ed$min/60
           ed_total <- ed_h + ed_m
           hours <- c(hours,ed_total)
        } else {
         hours <- as.numeric(difftime(d$WearEnd,d$WearStart, units = "hours"))
        }
  df <- data.frame(id = rep(d$ID, length(Days)), days = Days, hours = hours)
  return(df)
  }

  df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 0))
  colnames(df) <- c("id", "days", "hours")
  for ( i in 1:nrow(d)) {
   df <- rbind(df,timeInt(d[i,]))
  }

id       days      hours
1   1 2018-05-14 11.0000000
2   1 2018-05-14  4.5000000
3   1 2018-05-15 17.0000000
4   1 2018-05-16 22.5000000
5   1 2018-05-16  0.6666667
6   1 2018-05-17 23.0000000
7   1 2018-05-18 24.0000000
8   1 2018-05-19 15.0000000
9   2 2018-05-16  0.1666667
10  2 2018-05-16  1.9166667
11  2 2018-05-17 24.0000000
12  2 2018-05-18 24.0000000
13  2 2018-05-19 24.0000000
14  2 2018-05-20 24.0000000
15  2 2018-05-21 24.0000000
16  2 2018-05-22 22.7000000

#daily usage of device for each customer
res <- as.data.frame(tapply(df$hours, list(df$days,df$id), sum))
res[is.na(res)] <- 0
res$date <- rownames(res)
res
                  1         2       date
2018-05-14 15.50000  0.000000 2018-05-14
2018-05-15 17.00000  0.000000 2018-05-15
2018-05-16 23.16667  2.083333 2018-05-16
2018-05-17 23.00000 24.000000 2018-05-17
2018-05-18 24.00000 24.000000 2018-05-18
2018-05-19 15.00000 24.000000 2018-05-19
2018-05-20  0.00000 24.000000 2018-05-20
2018-05-21  0.00000 24.000000 2018-05-21
2018-05-22  0.00000 22.700000 2018-05-22
```

Comment: Hi @Farzad, great thank to your help! Your code fits my data very well! The only problem is a few output values are not correct which i am still trying to understand the reason. I would need to do some modification.