# Split row into multple rows based on time of day (shift changes)

Tags: r, dataframe, split, row

I have a dataset that is used for OEE monitoring of machines in a factory. Amongst other data, machines report their operational status automatically. The factory runs in 3 shifts:

- night: from 23:00:00 to 06:00:00 (7 hours)
- morning: from 06:00:00 to 14:30:00 (8.5 hours)
- evening: from 14:30:00 to 23:00:00 (8.5 hours)

The lines in the dataframe are not split upon shift-changes. Below is an example of the data that is available. In this example, the first line starts on 2023-03-09 23:30:00 and ends on 2023-03-10 15:30. This line should be split in three:

- night: from 23:30:00 to 06:00:00
- morning: from 06:00:00 to 14:30:00
- evening: from 14:30:00 to 15:30:00

It might be irrelevant to the solution, but be aware that report days run from 23:00:00 to 23:00:00, causing apparent misalignment between "report_date" and "starttime_report_day".

*Code-chunk to build example dataframe, based on dummy-data:*

```
df <-
  data.frame(
    starttime = c(
      as.POSIXct("2023-03-09 23:30:00"),
      as.POSIXct("2023-04-02 07:00:00"),
      as.POSIXct("2023-04-10 15:00:00")
    ),
    endtime = c(
      as.POSIXct("2023-03-10 15:30:00"),
      as.POSIXct("2023-04-02 15:00:00"),
      as.POSIXct("2023-04-10 16:00:00")
    ),
    operation_code = c("machine setup", "operational", "crash")
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    report_date = as.Date(ifelse(
      hour(starttime) < 23,
      as.Date(starttime),
      as.Date(starttime) + days(1)
    ), origin = "1970-01-01"),
    shift = case_when(
      hour(starttime) + minute(starttime) / 60 >= 23 |
        hour(starttime) + minute(starttime) / 60 < 6 ~ "night",
      hour(starttime) + minute(starttime) / 60 >= 6 &
        hour(starttime) + minute(starttime) / 60 < 14.5 ~ "morning",
      hour(starttime) + minute(starttime) / 60 >= 14.5 &
        hour(starttime) + minute(starttime) / 60 < 23 ~ "evening"
    ),
    starttime_report_day = as.POSIXct(report_date - days(1) + hours(23)),
    starttime_shift = case_when(
      shift == "night" ~ starttime_report_day,
      shift == "morning" ~ starttime_report_day + hours(7),
      shift == "evening" ~ starttime_report_day + hours(15) + minutes(30)
    ),
    endtime_shift = case_when(
      shift == "night" ~ starttime_report_day + hours(7),
      shift == "morning" ~ starttime_report_day + hours(15) + minutes(30),
      shift == "evening" ~ starttime_report_day + hours(24)
    )
  )
df
df
```

*Output of df:*

```
| starttime           | endtime             |  operation_code  | report_date  | shift   | starttime_report_day | starttime_shift     | endtime_shift       |
| ------------------- | ------------------- | ---------------- | ------------ | ------- | -------------------- | ------------------- | ------------------- |
| 2023-03-09 23:30:00 | 2023-03-10 15:30:00 | machine setup    | 2023-03-10   | night   | 2023-03-09 23:00:00  | 2023-03-09 23:00:00 | 2023-03-10 06:00:00 |
| 2023-04-02 07:00:00 | 2023-04-02 15:00:00 | operational      | 2023-04-02   | morning | 2023-04-01 23:00:00  | 2023-04-02 06:00:00 | 2023-04-02 14:30:00 | 
| 2023-04-10 15:00:00 | 2023-04-10 16:00:00 | crash            | 2023-04-10   | evening | 2023-04-09 23:00:00  | 2023-04-10 14:30:00 | 2023-04-10 23:00:00 |
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60232080/r-how-can-i-split-one-row-of-a-time-period-into-multiple-rows-based-on-day-and) to a somewhat similar question, where the rows had to be split on date-changes and as an exercise I got that to work on my dataset somewhat successfully.

*Code-chunk based on the solution found in the link above:*

```
# Helper Functions ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

endsOnOtherDay <- function(df) {
  as_date(df$starttime) != as_date(df$endtime)
}

split1rowInto2Days <- function(df) {
  df1 <- df
  df2 <- df
  df1$endtime <-
    as_date(df1$starttime) + days(1) - milliseconds(1)
  df2$starttime <- as_date(df2$starttime) + days(1)
  rbind(df1, df2)
}


splitDates <- function(df) {
  if (nrow(df) > 1) {
    return(df %>%
             split(f = 1:nrow(df)) %>%
             lapply(splitDates) %>%
             reduce(rbind))
  }
  
  if (df %>% endsOnOtherDay()) {
    return(df %>%
             split1rowInto2Days() %>%
             splitDates())
  }
  
  df
}

# The actual Calculation ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

df_split <- df %>%
  splitDates() %>%
  mutate(duration_hours = round(difftime(endtime + 1,
                               starttime,
                               units = "hours"), 3)
         ,
         date_calc = as_date(starttime)) %>%
  group_by(starttime,
           operation_code) %>%
  summarise(duration_hours = sum(duration_hours)) %>%
  mutate(
    endtime_calc = starttime + duration_hours,
    actual_date = as.Date(starttime),
    report_date = as.Date(ifelse(
      hour(starttime) < 23,
      as.Date(starttime),
      as.Date(starttime) + days(1)
    ), origin = "1970-01-01")
  )

df_split <- df_split %>% 
  mutate(shift = case_when(
      hour(starttime) + minute(starttime) / 60 >= 23 |
        hour(starttime) + minute(starttime) / 60 < 6 ~ "night",
      hour(starttime) + minute(starttime) / 60 >= 6 &
        hour(starttime) + minute(starttime) / 60 < 14.5 ~ "morning",
      hour(starttime) + minute(starttime) / 60 >= 14.5 &
        hour(starttime) + minute(starttime) / 60 < 23 ~ "evening"
    ))
df_split
```

*Output of df_split:*

```
| starttime           | operation_code | duration_hours | endtime_calc        | actual_date | report_date | shift   |
| ------------------- | -------------- | -------------- | ------------------- | ----------- | ----------- | ------- |
| 2023-03-09 23:30:00 | machine setup  | 1.5 hours      | 2023-03-10 01:00:00 | 2023-03-09  | 2023-03-10  | night   |
| 2023-03-10 01:00:00 | machine setup  | 14.5 hours     | 2023-03-10 15:30:00 | 2023-03-10  | 2023-03-10  | night   |
| 2023-04-02 07:00:00 | operational    | 8.0 hours      | 2023-04-02 15:00:00 | 2023-04-02  | 2023-04-02  | morning |
| 2023-04-10 15:00:00 | crash          | 1.0 hours      | 2023-04-10 16:00:00 | 2023-04-10  | 2023-04-10  | evening |
```

For some reason, the split in df_split is now made on 01:00:00, instead of the expected 00:00:00. Disregarding that slight error, this at least is proof that it is possible to make a split at all.
However, I don't want the rows of my dataframe to be split on date-changes, but on shift-changes (split when endtime exceeds endtime_shift), which seems a lot harder to do. I'd really appreciate some help with that.

*Desired output after row split:*

```
| starttime           | endtime             |  operation_code  | report_date  | shift   | starttime_report_day | starttime_shift     | endtime_shift       |
| ------------------- | ------------------- | ---------------- | ------------ | ------- | -------------------- | ------------------- | --------------------|
| 2023-03-09 23:30:00 | 2023-03-10 06:00:00 | machine setup    | 2023-03-10   | night   | 2023-03-09 23:00:00  | 2023-03-09 23:00:00 | 2023-03-10 06:00:00 |
| 2023-03-10 06:00:00 | 2023-03-10 14:30:00 | machine setup    | 2023-03-10   | morning | 2023-03-09 23:00:00  | 2023-03-09 06:00:00 | 2023-03-10 14:30:00 |
| 2023-03-10 14:30:00 | 2023-03-10 15:30:00 | machine setup    | 2023-03-10   | evening | 2023-03-09 23:00:00  | 2023-03-09 14:30:00 | 2023-03-10 23:00:00 |
| 2023-04-02 07:00:00 | 2023-04-02 14:30:00 | operational      | 2023-04-02   | morning | 2023-04-01 23:00:00  | 2023-04-02 06:00:00 | 2023-04-02 14:30:00 | 
| 2023-04-02 14:30:00 | 2023-04-02 15:00:00 | operational      | 2023-04-02   | evening | 2023-04-01 23:00:00  | 2023-04-02 14:30:00 | 2023-04-02 23:00:00 | 
| 2023-04-10 15:00:00 | 2023-04-10 16:00:00 | crash            | 2023-04-10   | evening | 2023-04-09 23:00:00  | 2023-04-10 14:30:00 | 2023-04-10 22:00:00 |
```